# Confidence interval from summaries in JMP

Tags: confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, sas, jmp

If i only have mean, std dev. and number of observations is it then possible to generate af 95% confidence interval or a Chi squared test in JMP using only these summaries as input?

Comment: A confidence interval for *what*, exactly?

Comment: For instance, sample mean.

Comment: You know the sample mean, you don't need an interval for it. I assume you mean an interval for the population mean. Yes, you can generate a 95% CI for that from mean, std dev. and number of observations, but it's not quite as simple as the answer you have suggests. In particular, the part about "n=30" is not true.

Comment: If you are prepared to assume normality or near normality, you can generate a t-interval; with sufficiently large samples and weaker assumptions you could generate a z-interval. Other intervals are possible. I don't know how to do any of them in JMP though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your sample size is "large enough" (typically considered to be $n>30$) you can apply the Central Limit Theorem which will result in a 95% confidence interval being $\bar{X} \pm 1.96\sqrt{\text{Var(}\bar{X})}$

A quick google search gives this webpage which shows you how to do it in JMP: http://stat.fsu.edu/tutorials/confidenceintervals/pc.html

Comment: The link you provided uses input data in jump. I am looking for a JMP formula where I just enter the summaries as the data input.

Comment: In that case, just use the formula I provided by hand/excel/R/etc.

Comment: I apologize, but my question is not how to calculate a confidence interval by hand, the question is how to use summaries as input data in JMP :-)